# Grant credential access to Windows SSH login

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, credentials

I'm trying to run `docker login` and `docker push` on a Windows machine that I've SSH'd into. I know that the same commands work when I'm logged in via Remote Desktop, but once I'm in SSH mode, they fail with this error:

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.``
```

I've seen online that it's related to SSH sessions not being granted the same credential access as a local login. BUT is there anything we can do to make that possible? I'd really like to handle these functions remotely (esp. from Jenkins)

Comment: have you tried `sudo docker login`? if it does not work, try deleting(or moving to a backup location) the file `~/.docker/config.json`

Comment: This is a windows machine - sudo doesn't exist on it, and removing config.json didn't fix anything